# GraphQL codegen generated mutation hooks

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-codegen

In my React application I am using graphQL code generator for generating query and mutation React hooks (I am using Apollo client). Generated queries work just fine, but when it comes to mutation I am getting this error :

**message: "Error trying to resolve field 'createSuborder'.", locations: [{line: 2, column: 3**

Here is my important part of graphQL schema :
[image]
[image]

Weird thing is that when I try to run this mutation in graphQL playground it works.
[image]

Here is my generated code from codegen, and hook used in my React component.
[image]

```
  const [createSuborderMutation, { data, loading, error }] =
    useCreateSuborderMutation({
      variables: {
        tableId: 17,
        meals: [{ id: 1, count: 2 }],
        drinks: [{ id: 1, count: 3 }],
        token: "bpTtlPuC",
      },
    });
```